# Android. DialogFragment, как запретить закрытие по тапу вне окна

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Сделал свое диалоговое окна через DialogFragment, все работает но хотелось бы что бы окно закрывалось только при нажатие на кнопку, а сейчас оно закрывается при тапе вне области диалогового окна. Как можно изменить такое поведение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
       ... 
       }
```

Comment: Вылетел с ошибкой void android.app.Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)' on a null object reference.  Прописал в фрагмент из которого вызываю диалог Fragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: @FredGan, `DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Моим решением стало просто после     `window = builder.setTitle.setView(tableLayout)`    итд

вставить    `window.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`   , в классе с созданием диалогового окна.